# SSIS: Comparing datetime with a variable

Tags: datetime, variables, ssis

So, I have created a variable "batch" with datatype datetime. Now my OLEBD source has a column "addDate"  eg 2012-05-18 11:11:17.470 so does empty destination which is to be populated.

now this column addDate has many dates and I want to copy all dates which are "2012-05-18 11:11:17.470"

When I put value of the variable as this date, it automatically changes to mm/dd/yyyy hh;mm AM format and hence in my conditional split transformation, it couldn't match the date with the variable and hence no records are getting copied to the destination !!

Where exactly is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easier solution. Select datatype as string. put any desired value.
Before conditional split, you need data conversion transformation.
convert it into DT_DBTIMESTAMP then run the package.

It works!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the best solution I found is not “pretty”.
Basically you need to change the “expression” of the variable and the “evaluate as expression” to true (otherwise it will ignore the value on expression).

The secret is (and kind of the reason I said it is not a pretty solution) to create a second variable to evaluate the expression of the first variable because you can’t change the value of a variable based on a expression.

So let’s say your variable is called “DateVariable” and you have `23/05/2012`, create a variable called “DateVar2” for example and set its expression to

> (DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(@[User::DateVariable]) + "/"+RIGHT("0" +
>   (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(@[User::DateVariable]),2) + "/" + RIGHT("0" +
>   (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(@[User::DateVariable]),2)

That will give you `2012/05/23`

Just keep going to get the date on the format you want